# Which lens with Canon700D for landscape and travel photography?

Tags: lens

I have got an iPhone X from which I have been taking landscape and travel photos. 
But I have also got a 700D with 18-55 and 55-250, which I never really used. 
Currently, I am not thinking of upgrading my camera but only my lens. Which lens do you think is the best for landscape, max up to 1500$ ?

Comment: You can use any of lenses you already have for landscape photography. Maybe you can buy also Canon 10-18. But better use the money for some photography training (and you will understand why you can shoot landscape even with telefoto lens like 55-250)

Comment: @Romeo Ninov I you posted your comment as an answer I would have upvoted it

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of lenses you already have for landscape photography. Maybe you can buy also Canon 10-18 to have something more wide

But better use the money for some photography training, course. This will help you understand why you can shoot landscape photos even with telephoto lens like 55-250. About travel my personal experience show me I need mostly telephoto and standard (something between 24 and 70 for fullframe) focal length.